# how to record speech from Line-in?

Tags: linux, audio-streaming, gstreamer, rtp, alsa

I am using Gstreamer to record speech and transmit in real-time( so RTP and UDP ). I have the following code :

**Receiver:**

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false
```

**Sender:**

```
 gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
```

This works perfectly but it transmits **Mono** Speech.I also know that my Mic input is Mono. So it means that i have to use the Line-in port which shall be connected by a double-Mic ( left and right, one end a double to single jack and the other end two microphones ).
Now my problem is that i cant seem to find a way to change the input signal source of `alsasrc` to `Line-in`. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use 0.10 ? If not, you should really switch to 1.0 as 0.10 is not maintained anymore and you will have trouble finding help if you encounter problems. As for the question, did you try using the "device" parameter on alsasrc ? I don't know about that element but gst-inspect alsasrc shows this property as writable, you might as well give it a shot ;)

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)